# Snow days per county per monthly in US specifically in Colorado?

Tags: data-request, usa, weather

I am seeking a detail monthly snow days where I can look it up for more accurate information. I have looked at the Weather Channel, RoCoRaHS,  Accuweather and others and it does not provide me more information and it is not what I am looking for.

What I want to focus the Snow days for each county all over the United States But I am more specific in Colorado.

Comment: As most school districts are monitored by the state to make sure that they have enough days of instruction, it's possible that there might be something that the state level (so you wouldn't have to contact each county individually).  If you view the Colorado Dept. of Ed, they have a link to 'Data Center', but I got a message of it being down for maintenance (with no indication if it's a short term (nightly backup) or long-term thing.  http://www.cde.state.co.us/schoolview.  "Data Lab" seemed to be more student info.

Comment: @Joe I don't think will work because it might be difficult to know what days that does snow or does not snow. Sometimes they don't maintenance very well.

Comment: So you're interested in the data, but not so much that you're not willing to contact the group that might actually have what you're looking for?  We can only help you so far.  Sometimes the data isn't in the format you want, or has to be inferred from two different sources.  In my state, counties put in an initial schedule, and it gets modified through the year.  If Colorado has both the 'as planned' and 'actual' schedules, you could likely get close to what you're trying to do.  You may need to cross-check it against weather (as there are other reasons schools might close, eg. shootings)

Comment: Problem solved I found this site http://climate.atmos.colostate.edu/

Comment: When you say "snow days", do you mean "days on which it snows", "days on which there is snow on the ground", or "days on which schools are closed because of snow"?

Comment: days on which it snows