# School Closing Due to Snow or Bad Weather

Tags: usa, weather, education

I am looking for a dataset that contains the amount of snow that will cause a school to close in the US either by school district, zip code, county or any subdivision smaller than state. I am familiar with [this](http://sashat.me/2014/01/29/snow-days/) map. However, there is no methodology provided besides a short description.

Comment: As you point out, they do say "Data was taken from hundreds of various points from user responses on Reddit and interpolated using NOAA’s average annual snowfall days map", so I think that's pretty much it. In many localities, there is not a fixed amount of snow that will close schools: it depends on other factors such as iciness, time of snowfall (whether it can be cleared), wind conditions, etc. Keep in mind some places put schools on a 2 hour delay first, and then close if conditions don't improve. And some districts only close SOME schools based on location.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read my past question I posted here...

[Snow days per county per monthly in US specifically in Colorado?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6668/snow-days-per-county-per-monthly-in-us-specifically-in-colorado)

See if that helps yours.

I am not sure for the whole country's school districts. I think that would be too much to perform that kind of work, however, I think maybe NOAA, or probably contact the National Weather Service and query about that . They might help you out where to find it. or contact the each state's Department of Education and ask them about it..

https://www.climate.gov/maps-data

Good Luck on finding it.